# getting type error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python

Tags: python, mysql

I am dumping the specific data from the .xls file to mysql database. While trying that i am getting the following error.

my .py file

```
import xlrd
import MySQLdb
book = xlrd.open_workbook("Sheet2.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="dtz_new")
cursor = database.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO property_property(name) VALUES(%s)"""
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    gaurav      = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    values = (gaurav)
    cursor.execute(query, values)
cursor.close()
database.commit()
database.close()
print "all done, Bye for now"
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)
print "I just imported "+ columns+ " columns and "+ rows+" rows to MySQL!"
```

Error i am getting is here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dtz_db.py", line 29, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query, values)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

the cell(1,1) value is Kunjvihar its a name charfield in python
Please help me out for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make `values` an actual tuple:

```
values = (gaurav,)
```

Note the *comma* there; just parenthesis only serve to group your expression, it is the comma that defines the expression as a tuple.

Without the comma, you have just one string value, which is also a sequence. MySQL then tries to insert just individual characters, and you have more than one character in your string value. With the extra characters an exception is thrown.

Comment: I am getting this error now "    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a fo
reign key constraint fails (`dtz_new`.`property_property`, CONSTRAINT `lease_id_
refs_id_816819bc` FOREIGN KEY (`lease_id`) REFERENCES `property_propertylease` (
`id`))')
"

Comment: @user3298313: that is an entirely new, unrelated problem. Your database schema has foreign key constraints that you are not adhering to. That'd be subject for a *new* question, but you do need to include enough detail about your database for people to be able to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot if i am not able to do that then i will post a new question,,,,,,, Hay can you give me one small answer, for string we write %s for char we write %c for int %d then what we should write for datefield?

Comment: For SQL parameters? Use *only* `%s` and let the database adapter worry about type conversions.

Comment: yah i did that but its throwing error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dtz_db.py", line 28, in <module>
    gaurav9             = sheet.cell(r,8).value
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.3-py2.7.egg\xlrd\sheet.py", line
399, in cell
    self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
IndexError: array index out of range"